# In JavaScript, Is assigning a class name to a regular element and a namespace element different?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, classname

```
function foo(){
  var svg = document.querySelector(".crusher");
  let polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
  polygon.className = "polygon01";
  svg.appendChild(polygon);
}

function foo01(){
  let actualPolygon = document.querySelector(".polygon01");
  actualPolygon.style = "fill:red";
}
```

When I try to select the class name, and change the fill color, i'm receiving a cannot access style of null value, so the class name is not being assigned the way I would like it to. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use setAttribute

```js
function foo(){
  var svg = document.querySelector(".crusher");
  let polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
  polygon.setAttribute('class', 'polygon01');
  svg.appendChild(polygon);
}

function foo01(){
  let actualPolygon = document.querySelector(".polygon01");
  actualPolygon.style = "fill:red";
}

foo()
foo01();
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGElement__className) for the SVG namespace you provided, it says that `className` is deprecated and to use `classList`.

```js
// create polygon and add class
let polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
polygon.classList.add("polygon01");

// append to element
document.querySelector(".crusher").appendChild(polygon);

// reference polygon with querySelector and add fill:red style
let actualPolygon = document.querySelector(".polygon01");
actualPolygon.style.fill = "red";
console.log(actualPolygon.style.fill);
```

```html
<div class="crusher">
```

Comment: Thank you, What made you think to check that update for SVG? Just wondering so I can try to self correct in the future.

Comment: Between us, that's the first time I've ever looked at a spec, which I only did because `createElementNS(...).className` looked weird compared to what we'd expect (an empty string, compare with `document.createElement('a').className` which returns `""`). 

The polygon `className` property actually spits out a weird-looking object that looks like `SVGAnimatedString {baseVal: "", animVal: ""}`, and I don't actually know what's happening there. It was enough to make me see if they broke `className` somehow and sure enough, it's deprecated for this namespace.

Comment: It looks like an interface for changing classes on the fly during animations or something:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString. Feel free to explore it a bit if you're curious.